# Binding a Stack (that can be switched) to a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a list of objects (`Man`) which each contains a `Stack` of states.
I have a Debug window which shows the **selected** `Man`'s stack in a `ListBox`.
And I have a TabControl which I use to select a Man to debug.

To be able to select the correct binding, I made a property which returns the `StateStack` of the man at the selected index of the `TabControl`.

```
public object StateStack => Men[DebugIndex].States;
```

`DebugIndex` is bound to the `TabControl`'s `SelectedIndex` property. So to make `DebugIndex` update the `StateStack` to show, I used `OnPropertyChanged`:

```
public int DebugIndex {
    get => _debugIndex;
    set {
        _debugIndex = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StateStack));
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the `TabControl`'s `SelectedIndex` changes, the `Stack` is weirdly disordered! Bug the thing is that it's disordered only in the View, not really in the data.

I think it comes from something with the fact that I change the reference of the Binding it's an other Stack but I don't know how to solve that...

By the way, it works when I add all the Man objects and initialize their StateStack at the beginning. But as soon as I add a Man (and initialize its StateStack) later, for example when I click a Button, it doesn't work anymore...

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private int _debugIndex;

    public ObservableCollection<Man> Men { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Man>();

    public MainWindow() {
        Men.Add(new Man {Index = 0, States = new StateStack()});

        InitializeComponent();

        Men[0].States.Push(new State {Name = "Falling1"});
        Men[0].States.Push(new State {Name = "Walking1"});

        //this is simplified code. I push states here because in my program it's done during runtime (not during initialization)
    }

    public object StateStack => Men[DebugIndex].States;

    public int DebugIndex {
        get => _debugIndex;
        set {
            _debugIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StateStack));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Men.Add(new Man {Index = 1, States = new StateStack()});

        Men[1].States.Push(new State {Name = "Falling2"});
        Men[1].States.Push(new State {Name = "Walking2"});
        Men[1].States.Push(new State {Name = "Running2"});
    }
}

public class Man {
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public StateStack States { get; set; }
}

public class State {
    public string Name { private get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name;
    }
}

public sealed class StateStack : Stack<State>, INotifyCollectionChanged {

    public new void Push(State item) {
        base.Push(item);

        OnCollectionChanged(
            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, Count - 1));
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

And my View code:

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableStackBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="Add" Margin="5" Padding="8 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding StateStack}" Grid.Row="1" />

        <TabControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Men}" SelectedIndex="{Binding DebugIndex}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

What could I do to say to my binding that when DebugIndex is changed, StateStack is a **very other Stack**?

Comment: Add `OnPropertyChanged` for `StateStack` property too, so when binding of `StateStack` changes it will notify to bound source too.

Comment: Also, any specific reason you have defined the `StateStack`  as object. (The problem mentioned by you is not specific to  object return type - It more like a coding observation)

Comment: @user1672994 I'll change that, that's just because I used the automatic property creation with ReSharper ^^

Comment: @user1672994 what you said doesn't work, and I already use OnPropertyChanged(nameof(**StateStack**)); in `DebugIndex` property

Comment: I've simulated your scenario and observation is that there is problem with Push method for how the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` is item changed is propagated to source. The current code notifies that the from the end index, items are added. If you update the notification as  NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, 0) then bound source will display the item in appropriate order in the view.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna test that, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simulated your scenario and observation is that there is problem with `Push` method for how the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` is item changed is propagated to source. The current code notifies that items are changed from the end index (but for stack the items are added at Top)). If you update the notification start index to `0` as `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, 0)` then bound source will display the item in appropriate order in the view. You can read about NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653208(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public new void Push(State item) {
    base.Push(item);

    OnCollectionChanged(
        new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, 0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. For information for a possible future reader, I used 0 for the Pop() method too...